# How to get the Textbox's ID inside a Gridview using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

**I have searched for a while but i couldn't find an answer to my situation**

This is my problem:

I have a **Textbox** inside a **Gridview** like this:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:DCAAStrategicManagement, obj_lblStandardWeight  %>" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtStandardWeight" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers();" Text='<%# Eval("StandardWeight") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

And i need to set a **blur event** on that **TextBox** using **JQuery**.

This is my attempt to achieve that:

```
 $("input[id*='<%=txtStandardWeight.ClientID %>']").blur(function () {
    Read();
    var currentSum = document.getElementById('<%=hidden.ClientID %>').value;
    var oldLabelData = $('#<%= lblStandardWeightCurrently.ClientID %>').value;
    var newLabelData = oldLabelData + currentSum;
    $('#<%= lblStandardWeightCurrently.ClientID %>').value(newLabelData);
 })
```

This function should change the `lblStandardWeightCurrently` **Text** whenever the `blur` even occurs. 
But There is no changes in **lblStandardWeightCurrently** label..

**Read() Function:**

```
function Read() {
    debugger;
    var oDataGrid = document.getElementById("<%= grdPlanObjectivesStandardWeights.ClientID %>");
    var tableRows = oDataGrid.rows;
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
        var col1 = oDataGrid.rows[i].cells[2];
        for (j = 0; j < col1.childNodes.length; j++) {
            if (col1.childNodes[j].type == "text") {
                if (!isNaN(col1.childNodes[j].value) && col1.childNodes[j].value != "") {
                    sum += parseInt(col1.childNodes[j].value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!isNaN(sum)) {
        document.getElementById('<%=hidden.ClientID %>').value = sum;
    }
}
```

**I think the problem is here:**
`$("input[id*='<%=txtStandardWeight.ClientID %>']").blur(function ()`
since i can't debug this function .
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can achieve by creating an event directly  onblur="funcName();" may be your jquery funcion did not work because you can't access textbox directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your textbox is inside a template. That means that it actually does not exist until grid view is databound, and even what it is, there are many textboxes, one per row, each having a different ID. That means that you cannot simply access it by `txtStandardWeight`.

However since you are using jQuery anyway, why don't assign some class to the textbox which would allow you to query for it easily?

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtStandardWeight" CssClass="weightText" ...

$("input.weightText").blur(function () {
```

One more thing - make sure your javascript is defined in .aspx file, otherwise syntax `<%# %>` won't work.

Comment: @Null, it most certainly works in general. What exactly does not work in your case?

Comment: `$("input[id*=txtStandardWeight").click(function ()` works just fine, but `$("input[id*=txtStandardWeight").blur(function ()` doesn't get triggered! i can't even debug it!

Answer (score 1):

```
$().ready(function () {
            $("#<%= text.ClientID%>").find("tr").each(function () {
                $(this).find("td").each(function () {
                    $(this).find("input[id*=txtStandardWeight]").blur(function () {
                        alert("Hello");
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

Let's take an example where **gridview** has **id=text** and your **textbox** has an **id=txtStandardWeight** then we have to traverse each row and column to get proper result and when you find your textbox then manage the proper functioning according to you.

Comment: actually when Gridview is displayed on the webpage then it will converted into a table you can check the view source of the page.